# Stuck in Immutable.js setIn method

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I just test the following code under the [Immutable.js](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) docs console in Chrome version 50, but it emit a error message: `Uncaught Error: invalid keyPath(…)`

```
var map1 = Immutable.Map({
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 1
    }
});

var map2 = map1.setIn(['b', 'c'], 2);
```

And then I changed the code to :

```
var map1 = Immutable.fromJS({
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 1
    }
});

var map2 = map1.setIn(['b', 'c'], 2);
```

It just works fine. But why? What's the difference between `fromJS` and `Map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Map`, `List` and other methods don't **deeply** convert the given data structure into immutables. In this case, the nested object `b` remains a plain JavaScript Object within the immutable map `map1`. Here's a console dump of `map1` to depict the same...
[image]

This is why you should prefer `fromJS`, which [deeply converts the data structure into immutables](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS). Here's a dump of `map1` which spawned from the `fromJS` call -
[image]

Notice that `b` is now of the same type (Map minified as `Lt`) as `map1`.

There's another way to do deep conversion -

```
var map1 = Immutable.Map().merge({
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 1
    }
});
```

Note that [merge internally invokes `fromJS` only](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/merge) :).

Comment: Great answer! I just find the problem via debugging the  `updateInDeepMap` method in source code, and your answer makes me more clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is the set path in .Map that is already been used, however it is not in .fromJs

try to change the set path.